# Sum of chromatic numbers of a graph and its complement - lower bound

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Here is my problem: Let $\chi(G)$ be a chromatic number of $G$. Suppose that $G$ is a simple graph with $n$ vertices. Let $\bar{G}$ be the complement of $G$ Prove that: $$\chi(G) + \chi(\bar{G}) \geq 2\sqrt{n}.$$ I tried induction but with no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

I know it's been discussed here: [chromatic number of a graph versus its complement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78301/chromatic-number-of-a-graph-versus-its-complement), but I can't find the proof of above statement.

Many thanks,
Szymon

Comment: Are you familiar with lower bounds on the product $\chi(G) \chi(\bar G)$?

Answer (score 1):

Show that $\chi(G).\chi(\bar{G})≥n$
This follows from the fact that for any graph $H$, $\chi(H)≥w(H)$ where $w(H)$ is the clique number and also we have $\chi(H)≥(|H|/\alpha(H))$ where $\alpha(H)$ is the size of the maximal independent set in $H$
The first one is pretty obvious for the second one note that if $k$ is the chromatic number then the vertices of color i form an independent set of size $≤\alpha(H)$ and then you sum over all $i$. Another observation is $w(\bar{H})=\alpha(H)$
Finally use the AM GM inequality on $\chi(G)$ & $ \chi(\bar{G})$

Comment: Could you explain the "then you sum over all i" part? What should I sum over I? I think I understand the rest.

Comment: I meant $i$ running from $1$ to $k$ where $k$ is the chromatic number